# Implement UDP Sockets in RUST on esp32

Tags: sockets, rust, esp-idf, esp-idf-sys

I want to create a communication between my esp32 and my raspberry pi. I want to use UDP Sockets for this.
I found [documentation](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/protocols/sockets/udp_server/README.md) for sockets in Rust and for esp-idf Sockets but in c.

As far as i understand I can't just use normal c-Sockets because they are only working on unix systems. So I need to use esp-idf sockets.

I found [this](https://esp-rs.github.io/esp-idf-svc/esp_idf_svc/tls/trait.Socket.html?search=socket#tymethod.release) but struggle to interpret it good enough to use it.

So where can I implement UDP Sockets in rust on esp32 and where can I find documentation.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [Embassy](https://embassy.dev/). It offers a nice asynchronous network stack, and you should be able to use it with an ESP32 HAL.